# jQuery keyboard navigation breaks on Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, keyboard, cross-browser

The following code reveals a div on a keypress event of '?' (191). Works perfectly with Google Chrome but refuses to work with Firefox. Any ideas?

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
  if(e.which == 16) isShift=false; }).keydown(function (e) {

  if(e.which == 16) isShift=true;

  if(e.which == 191 && isShift == true) {
    if ($('#keyboard-shortcut-menu').css('display') == 'none') {
      $('#keyboard-shortcut-menu').show();
    } else {
      $('#keyboard-shortcut-menu').hide();
    }

  return false;
}
```

UPDATE: Figured this one out. Firefox captures '?' char as 0 value. Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it. I ran this script on Firefox console:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  console.log(e.which);
});
```

It seems Firefox captures the '?' char as value 0, while Google Chrome captures it as 191.

Solved it by adding a conditional code:

```
if((e.which == 191 && isShift == true) || (e.which == 0 && isShift == true))
```

Thanks for all the refactoring tips.

Answer (score 2):

try with

```
e.keyCode == XX
```

oh, and you can use `e.shiftKey` to test if "shift" key is pressed

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
  if(e.keyCode==191 && e.shiftKey)
    $('#keyboard-shortcut-menu').toggle();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: `keypress` & `keyCode` aren't supported in Firefox (ref: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html), it's best to use `e.which` which is normalized in jQuery.

Comment: yes, the page is 2 years old, but try the demo at the bottom while using Firefox, `keypress` + `keyCode` always shows 0.

Comment: Agreed with @fudgey: `keydown` and `e.which` are definitely best.

Answer (score 1):

i think you were missing a ; or } cos this works in FF:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).keyup(function (e) {
          if(e.which == 16) isShift=false;
    }).keydown(function (e) {

          if(e.which == 16) isShift=true;

          if(e.which == 191 && isShift == true) {
                if ($('#keyboard-shortcut-menu').css('display') == 'none') {
                      $('#keyboard-shortcut-menu').show();
                }
                  else {
                      $('#keyboard-shortcut-menu').hide();
                }

              return false;
            }
      });
  });
```

try the js fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/q3d6S/1/

Comment: Thanks. I now see the problem. The fiddle you've added also breaks on Firefox. Probably a local error on my installation. I'll test it a bit more on that angle. Thanks!

Comment: You could use `e.shiftKey` instead of using `e.which == 16`

Comment: yea, if this code breaks, there is something wrong somewhere else, b/c i ran that in IE, FF and Chrome :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NL6f8/)):

```
$(document).keyup(function(e){
    if (e.which == 191 && e.shiftKey == true) {
        $('#keyboard-shortcut-menu').toggle();
    }
});
```